# Run Multiple Scripts with Error Handling in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I need to run two R scripts in sequence. I am not asking about running scripts in parallel.

Each script has a stop-if-error logic inside. So if I run either of them separately, the execution will halt when an error occurs. The problem is, when I put them in a wrapper code like this:

```
source('script1.r', echo=T)
source('script2.r', echo=T)
```

and when an error occurs in `script1.r`, R will move on to execute `script2.r`.

How do I tell R to stop completely and not to move on in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the code in the two scripts in functions, source the scripts and then call the functions in the main file. If one function fails the script should stop.

(This may depend on how you execute the script, for example if you select code in Rstudio and run by CMD+Enter it will continue after errors.)

Comment: The problem was with RStudio. If I run it from command line, it will stop when the error in script1 occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with `try()`. I put the following in `script1.R`:

```
stop("Stop")
```

In `script2.R` I have

```
print("A")
```

Then from a "master script", I call

```r
x <- try(source("script1.R", echo = TRUE))
#> 
#> > stop("Stop")
if ( !inherits(x, "try-error") ) {
    source("script2.R", echo = TRUE)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

If the `stop()` portion is called (or any error occurs), `x` will be of class `try-error`, and the second `source()` call will not be executed.